# Insert values from multiple column in single column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am comparing data from two tables - `Table A` and `Table B`. I would like to create temporary table or view which will only return the mismatched records and store the mismatched messages from every column into single column .

I only have read permission to Database so is there a way to get the desired output creating Views/?

Data looks like this:

| FirstNameCheck | EmailCheck | TelephoneCheck | TableAFirstName | TableAEmail | TableATelephone | TableBFirstName | TableBEmail | TableBTelephone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MATCHED | MATCHED | MISMATCHED IN TELEPHONE | Pano | abc@gmail.com | 123222 | Pano | abc@gmail.com | NULL |
| MATCHED | MISMATCHED IN EMAIL | MISMATCHED IN TELEPHONE | Brian | esd@gmail.com | NULL | Brian | NULL | 123456 |
| MATCHED | MATCHED | MATCHED | William | NULL | 132777 | William | NULL | 132777 |
| MATCHED | MATCHED | MISMATCHED IN TELEPHONE | Bill | NULL | 145678 | Bill | NULL | 145669 |
| MATCHED | MATCHED | MISMATCHED IN TELEPHONE | Robin | NULL | 132444 | Robin | NULL | 132456 |

Expected result:

| Error_Message | TableAFirstName | TableAEmail | TableATelephone | TableBFirstName | TableBEmail | TableBTelephone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MISMATCHED IN TELEPHONE | Pano | abc@gmail.com | 123222 | Pano | abc@gmail.com | NULL |
| MISMATCHED IN EMAIL--MISMATCHED IN TELEPHONE | Brian | esd@gmail.com | NULL | Brian | NULL | 123456 |
| MISMATCHED IN TELEPHONE | Bill | NULL | 145678 | Bill | NULL | 145669 |
| MISMATCHED IN TELEPHONE | Robin | NULL | 132444 | Robin | NULL | 132456 |

Query which I tried and got stuck to get new column with error_messages

```
SELECT column1, 2
FROM (query-which gives the sample data) 
WHERE (FirstNameCheck = 'MISMATCHED IN FIRST NAME' OR EmailCheck = 'MISMATCHED IN EMAIL' OR TelephoneCheck = 'MISMATCHED IN TELEPHONE')
```

Can someone please help me how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So what's stopping you exactly? What's wrong with a traditional `INSERT` statement?

Comment: Due to insufficient privilege to DB , I can't use this INSERT . Any alternative please

Comment: Then you can't `INSERT`... No magic will allow you to `INSERT` into a table you don't have permissions to. Talk to your DBA about the problem, as we can't help you get around tha.

Comment: Can you "SELECT * INTO ##tblTemp FROM (SELECT statement)" to get your data into a temp table, then have someone write you a stored procedure to process it?

Comment: That requires now permissions than an `INSERT` @swolfe2 , which the OP says they can't do.

Comment: And please update your question explaining all your limitations.

Comment: @Larnu That wouldn't apply to tempdb though, right?

Comment: Please show the code you have actually tried and not just comments that may not get read so we may perhaps assist you better here.

Comment: If they can't `INSERT` in `tempdb` then they have much bigger fish to fry, @swolfe2 . That might suggest they are on a read only instance or something...

Comment: Sorry @Larnu, I read their post as not having read permissions in the database and not within the MSSQL server that houses the database.

Comment: They're prior [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75188280/insert-values-from-multiple-column-in-single-column?noredirect=1#comment132680354_75188280) says they can't use a "traditional" `INSERT`, @swolfe2 : *"Due to insufficient privilege to DB , I can't use this INSERT . Any alternative please"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `CASE` expressions and `CONCAT_WS` to accomplish this. Long story short, I nullify "match" instances and then concatenate the mismatches into one column.

**Note:** `CONCAT_WS` only works on SQL Server 2017 or later. If you're on an earlier version of SQL Server just use the regular `CONCAT` function.

**SQL:**

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT_WS(' -- ', [FirstNameCheck_MisMatch], [EmailCheck_MisMatch], [TelephoneCheck_MisMatch]) AS Error_Message, 
  a.[TableAFirstName], 
  a.[TableAEmail], 
  a.[TableATelephone], 
  a.[TableBFirstName], 
  a.[TableBEmail], 
  a.[TableBTelephone] 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
      CASE WHEN a.[FirstNameCheck] <> 'MATCHED' THEN a.[FirstNameCheck] END AS [FirstNameCheck_MisMatch], 
      CASE WHEN a.[EmailCheck] <> 'MATCHED' THEN a.[EmailCheck] END AS [EmailCheck_MisMatch], 
      CASE WHEN a.[TelephoneCheck] <> 'MATCHED' THEN a.[TelephoneCheck] END AS [TelephoneCheck_MisMatch], 
      a.[FirstNameCheck], 
      a.[EmailCheck], 
      a.[TelephoneCheck], 
      a.[TableAFirstName], 
      a.[TableAEmail], 
      a.[TableATelephone], 
      a.[TableBFirstName], 
      a.[TableBEmail], 
      a.[TableBTelephone] 
    FROM 
      ERROR_CHECK a) a
  /* RETURN ONLY RECORDS WHERE MISMATCH HAPPEN */
WHERE 
  COALESCE(a.[FirstNameCheck_MisMatch], a.[EmailCheck_MisMatch], a.[TelephoneCheck_MisMatch]) IS NOT NULL;
```

**Result:**

| Error_Message | TableAFirstName | TableAEmail | TableATelephone | TableBFirstName | TableBEmail | TableBTelephone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MISMATCHED IN TELEPHONE | Pano | abc@gmail.com | 123222 | Pano | abc@gmail.com | (null) |
| MISMATCHED IN EMAIL -- MISMATCHED IN TELEPHONE | Brian | esd@gmail.com | (null) | Brian | (null) | 123456 |
| MISMATCHED IN TELEPHONE | Bill | (null) | 145678 | Bill | (null) | 145669 |
| MISMATCHED IN TELEPHONE | Robin | (null) | 132444 | Robin | (null) | 132456 |

**SQL Fiddle:**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2a640e/11